# Chat service based on AWS

Tags: android, amazon-web-services

I am trying to create an Android app which allows the user to create chat rooms. I am working with AWS and I am thinking about building it on SQS (it can store messages for no longer than 14 days but it isn't a problem). Is it the best way to do it or there is another option to do it using different AWS service?

Comment: Can you elaborate on what you are trying to accomplish with SQS? Will chat messages be stored (DynamoDB)? Will you use push notifications (SNS) to deliver messages to the devices? The architecture will likely be a combination of services instead of a single service.

Answer (score -1):

You can use AWS Simple Workflow Service. It a much larger service than a queue, but also workflow functionality. You can browse the limitations here: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazonswf/latest/developerguide/swf-dg-limits.html. For instance it keeps messages up to one year. 
In both cases, it's probably a good option to use the serverless service AWS Lambda for executing your code. 
If you expect to process a large number of messages, you can check Kinesis, which can move and process large amount of data.
I would you should move serverless with SQS + Lambda or SWF + Lambda.

Comment: A chat application is not a good use-case for Simple Workflow Service. Refer to the SWF FAQ (https://aws.amazon.com/swf/faqs/).